# Por que a função onclick não funciona em um hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando criar um ícone que quando houver um `click` nele as informações sejam salvas, através de um `sessionStorage`, e ao mesmo tempo seja redirecionado a uma outra página onde vou preenchê-la através das informações da `sessionStorage`. Estou usando essa div:

```html
<a href="icone.html" onclick=pegarInfo()>
```

Alguém poderia me explicar o por que não funciona? e como eu posso contornar essa situação?

Comment: Caro Igor, o pegarInfo não vai funcionar pq provavelmente o href direciona antes do javascript ser executado (cc @MarceloBoni)

Comment: @sam é uma função que apenas armazena as informações com um sessionStorage.

Comment: Já tentou colocar o diretório de pastas? Como `..\icone.html`

Comment: @sam, considerando os 1% restante, colocaria um `window.location` na função `pegarInfo()`

Comment: Beleza, se ele colocar um alert  na função vai ver que o onclick funciona antes do href

Comment: @sam funciona de maneira intermitente ou que oscila não é funcionar, no momento que redirecionar de pagina, mesmo que algum script esteja em execução algo vai ser destruido podendo ou não falhar, isso ai não tem sentido e nem deve ser feito, as coisas tem que ser planejadas para funcionar e não por "talvez funcione" ou "acho que funciona". Simplesmente href="icone.html" vai redirecionar e neste momento qualquer tentativa de executar script em uma pagina que esta descarregando para carregar outra será um fator de "concorrência" não há garantias.

Comment: @sam fazer certo é bem diferente do que esta feito ali, por isso eu já comentei não vai funcionar, pq simplesmente tem que refazer. É questão de segundos, não tem meio certo nisso, e nem depender de navegador.

Comment: @Igor provavelmente seria melhor explicar o que quer fazer. Normalmente ou você usa href, ou o onclick. Dificilmente vai haver razão real para usar os dois (talvez você tenha a impressão de ser necessário no seu caso, mas provavelmente é falta de saber uma solução real - provavelmente de por o redirecionamento no JS).

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo com window.location.assign("imovel.html") funciona perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Bacco bom eu estou querendo que quando a pessoa clica no link o navegador guarde as informações e redirecione a pessoa para outra página, e na página que foi redirecionada eu consiga buscar as informações do navegador e complete as lacunas como "Nome" etc.

Comment: @sam é o que o bacco disse e o que eu disse, é o timing, o mesmo que eu disse: "É questão de segundos" ou menos ainda que segundos. Isso é chamado de "concorrência" no tempo de execução de duas tarefas.

Comment: Igor Costa é a forma mais sensata a ser aplicada (window.location dentro da função) . Veja como sua pergunta rendeu uma longa discussão rs

Comment: @IgorCosta nesse caso me parece realmente que a solução do Leo é adequada, tirar o href e deixar o link no location. Assim é garantido que vai rodar o código desejado, e o location vai fazer seu papel só depois. E mesmo assim tem que ver se o código executado é síncrono. Se for assincrono, ainda assim pode dar um problema de timing (o location matar seu JS antes dele terminar).

Comment: Me calha lembrar um post no facebook de um certo moderador da rede que eu compartilhei.... o seu comentário  "levantando a possibilidade de funcionar normalmente", **O errado continua sendo errado mesmo que todos façam errado, e o certo continua sendo certo mesmo que ninguém faça certo.**

Answer (score 3):

Considerando os comentários do @Guilherme Nascimento:

> funciona de maneira intermitente ou que oscila não é funcionar, no momento que redirecionar de pagina, mesmo que algum script esteja em execução algo vai ser destruido podendo ou não falhar, isso ai não tem sentido e nem deve ser feito, as coisas tem que ser planejadas para funcionar e não por "talvez funcione" ou "acho que funciona". Simplesmente href="icone.html" vai redirecionar e neste momento qualquer tentativa de executar script em uma pagina que esta descarregando para carregar outra será um fator de "concorrência" não há garantias.

**Sugiro que retire o href e coloque window.location na função pegarInfo()**

Porque usar ou uma `onclick` ou outra `href`?

Imagine um cenário de concorrência

```js
function pegarInfo(){
  setTimeout(function(){
      alert("isso deve executar dentro de 2 segundos");
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<a href="icone.html" onclick="pegarInfo()">Teste</a>
```

```js
function pegarInfo(){
  setTimeout(function(){
      alert("isso deve executar dentro de 2 segundos");
      window.location = "icone.html";
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="pegarInfo()">Teste</a>
```